# Remove Rows From Data Frame where a Row match from a list

Tags: r, filter, merge, conditional-statements

Remove Rows From Data Frame where a value matches from a list >
I have a list of account as following:

```
ANrule4 <- 
Group_Account
2911
2944
2949
1415
1695
1761
1912
2570
```

but i want to remove any of the account listed in following list :

```
2911
2946
2945
2944
2949
```

I am using following code:

```
ANrules4ex <- ANrule4%>%
              filter(!(Group_Account==2946 | Group_Account==2945 | Group_Account==2944 | Group_Account==2942 | Group_Account==2941 |   Group_Account==2912 | Group_Account==2911 | Group_Account==2910 ))
```

this is working fine but actually my list is very long and dynamic, I want to store exclusion list in one list and and want to merge these two keeping all account listed in exclusion list but not sure how to do that. Can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `anti_join` from the `dplyr` package.

```
ANrule4 <-
  data.frame(Group_Account = c(2911, 2944, 2949, 1415, 1695, 1761, 1912, 2570))

listremove <-
  data.frame(Group_Account = c(2911, 2946, 2945, 2944, 2949))

ANrule4 %>% anti_join(listremove, by = "Group_Account")

  Group_Account
1          1415
2          1695
3          1761
4          1912
5          2570
```

Comment: Thanks Dealec it's perfect and easiest way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`df` is your `data.frame` and `data` is a vector that you would like to compare.

```
df[!(df$Group_Account %in% data),]
```

Comment: sorry Saurabh but It did not work for me, I tried in following way :                                 fm1 <- read.csv("ls1.csv") ## All account
fm2 <- read.csv("ls2.csv")## exclusion list                                                            
 fnl <- fm1[!(fm1$Group_Account %in% fm2),]## I was expecting in fnl should have all account except kept in fm2, code ran without error but it created a NULL data set

Comment: @Ashish: It's working on your sample data. Please provide the reproducible example.